# Is there a web-app that will run custom editable JavaScript and host an image of the resulting rendered page?

Tags: web-apps, javascript, images

I want to show the result of some custom JavaScript in a GitHub readme, ideally in such a way that others could go and edit the JavaScript and see the altered results via a link. Web-apps like [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and [Codepen](https://codepen.io/) allow embedding the result of arbitrary JavaScript, and having other users edit and experiment with it, but they only allow embedding the result in an iframe, which is not allowed in GitHub markdown. What I'm looking for is a web-app that will also store the resulting rendered image so I can then reference the image in the restricted markdown.

I understand that the hosting costs of source code are drastically cheaper than images, so it's very likely that such a web-app doesn't exist. I'm also interested in other workarounds. My temporary solution is going to be to use one of the web-apps listed and use a DOM screen capture tool to take a screenshot just of the rendered DOM. This is a little more manual than I wanted, but does work.

Comment: Welcome Erik!  We offer recommendations for software (including web-apps) here, not websites.  What you're looking for is right on the edge of a web-app and a website, so I've gone ahead and edited your well-written question to make it more on-topic here.